# PHP facebook graphapi getting "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have this PHP code that i need help with

here is what i have

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId'  => FB_APP_ID,
            'secret' => FB_APP_SECRET,
            'cookies' => 'true'
        ));

$FBuser = $facebook->getUser();

$token_url =    "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
                            "client_id=" . FB_APP_ID .
                            "&client_secret=" . FB_APP_SECRET .
                            "&grant_type=client_credentials";
```

So far so good.. but then i try

```
$permissions = $facebook->api("/me/permissions");
```

And i get the error 
 "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

I know the user has already installed my app. I must be missing something simple??

Thanks
Randy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
$token_url =    "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
                            "client_id=" . FB_APP_ID .
                            "&client_secret=" . FB_APP_SECRET .
                            "&grant_type=client_credentials";
```

Simply gets an access token for the APP. There is no user attached to this. Read this [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/) about getting a user's login url. Then, the facebook SDK you have at that redirect_uri will finish the job for you, and get you an `access_token`. From there you just need to call `$permissions = $facebook->api("/me/permissions");` and it should work just fine.

To be sure, after you get that `access_token` in your current script, run it in the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to ensure a user_id is tied to it.